# Can I extract methods which modify the state in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm starting to learn Dart + Flutter and I developed a simple app with one single .dart file. I have several variables in my state, several methods which modify them, as well as some buttons which modify those variables when `onPressed` is called. Here's the simplified example:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  List<int> list = List.generate(/* something something */);
  ...
  void firstMethod() {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
  }
  ...
  RaisedButton methodThatBuildsButton(){
    return RaisedButton(
      ...
      onPressed: () {
        setState((){
          list.add(1);
        });
      });
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

And so on...

Since I would like to have a nice clean "main" file (if possible, with `build` method only), I was wondering if there is a way to extract all those methods to a separate class, and to call them from the main class? Maybe there is a way to pass the state somehow (as a parameter maybe?), so it could be modified from another class?

Comment: you should look for global/app state and the state management tools

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can using what we call "mixins".

Here's an example:

```dart
mixin MyMixin {
   // a variable defined on the modified class that this mixin uses
   //
   // It is voluntarily not a concrete implementation, as we don't want the mixin
   // to define those variables, but let the class that use it handle the definition instead
  int get count;
  set count(int value);

  void increment() {
    count += 1;
  }
}

// We apply the mixin using the `with` keyword
class Counter with MyMixin {
  int count = 0;
}

void main() {
  final counter = Counter();

  print(counter.count); // 0
  counter.increment();
  print(counter.count); // 1
}
```